# Extend a generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics, code-injection

is it possible in Java to let a class extend a generic type, so that you can inject an method into any class passed through your code? (Or is there any other way to inject or override methods into an existing class with Java?)

What I mean with "extend a generic type" is something like this (Class "T extends GameObject" belongs to game and may not be changed AND is unknown because loaded into the game at runtime (from other mods)):

```
class GameObject {
    void moveForward(float amount) {
        this.camera.z += amount;
    }
}

class Extender<T extends GameObject> extends T {
    void onTick(float time) {
        this.camera.z -= amount;
    }
}
```

onTick is called by the GameEngine, and in this way I could replace every existing game object with a version that moves backwards on every tick.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use it?

Comment: Game mod (minecraft): You want to override/inject methods into a existing block to alter it's behaviour without the need to change game files (for compatibility reasons)

Comment: I meant: can you show an example of code that would benefit from this feature?

Comment: I don't really see how those two problems (injecting code on one hand, and extending a generic type on the other hand) are connected. Even if `class Extender <T> extends T` worked, it would be useless since you could not use any member fields or methods of `T` in your class `Extender` (since `T` could be anything, no members are guaranteed to exist). If you're actually asking about injecting code only, I suggest you rephrase your question to avoid the misleading idea that you want to extend generic types.

Comment: This would make no sense really. What methods would you expect to share in common between all parameters of type `T`? If you want to override behavior in a class theres already a way to do that - simply extend it. But if you want to actually change the implementation of an existing class you have no control over then you should look into using AOP.

Comment: Aggregation before Inheritance? You could make a class Extender that has a T and implements the same interface ... Decorator pattern, I guess? But then again that member could as well be typed as the interface itself instead of T ...

Comment: I just added some example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You cannot extend a generic supertype. You can extend classes that make use of generic types (e.g. `public class MyClass<T> extends TheirClass<T>`) but you cannot extend a purely generic type.

Comment: I know that the code is wrong, the question was if there is any other way to do that!

Comment: @Mike Would you agree that the DecoratorPattern could be a possible alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can find the solution not in language's features, but in some design pattern, as [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method).

If the behaviour is determinated in runtime, you could give a look at [behaviour patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern).

Comment: The problem is that I can't affect anything else than the Extender class. I how to do something like this if I have the complete code, but in this case I HAVE to edit a class that already exists (and I can't change that class)